# How do i update data in nested field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I update a subelement data in nested field

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5efc287809c3635ae4977df0"),
    "deviceid" : "f7dd4c1b-d7b1-4d1b-9ab0-b0fa52b1f7e7",
    "solution" : []
}
```

I need to update same as below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5efc287809c3635ae4977df0"),
    "deviceid" : "f7dd4c1b-d7b1-4d1b-9ab0-b0fa52b1f7e7",
    "solution" : [ 
        {
            "solutionid" :1.0
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query.

```
db.collection.updateOne({"deviceid" : "f7dd4c1b-d7b1-4d1b-9ab0-b0fa52b1f7e7"},{"$set":{"solution":[{"solutionid" :1.0}]}})
```